# Histogram matching of two Images without using histeq

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

It is well known that `histeq` in MATLAB can perform histogram matching so that an image's histogram is transformed to look like another histogram.  I am trying to perform this same operation without using `histeq`.  I'm aware that you need to calculate the CDFs between the two images, but I'm not sure what to do next.  What do I do?

Comment: i see.nut i want histogram matching two image

Comment: I wrote an answer.  Do you need any further assistance?

Comment: yes. i think cdf is wrong in your code . CDFis propability and you shoud use this: probc=cumsum(freq)/numel(GIm);

Comment: Other than normalizing the CDF, the code is right.  That's one thing I forgot to do, so thank you for that correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Histogram matching is concerned with transforming one image's histogram so that it looks like another.  The basic principle is to compute the histogram of each image individually, then compute their discrete [cumulative distribution functions (CDFs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).  Let's denote the CDF of first image as [image] while the CDF of the second image is [image].  Therefore, [image] would denote what the CDF value is for intensity `x` for the first image.

Once you calculate the CDFs for each of the images, you need to compute a mapping that transforms one intensity from the first image so that it is in agreement with the intensity distribution of the second image.  To do this, for each intensity in the first image - let's call this [image] which will be from `[0,255]` assuming an 8-bit image - we must find an intensity [image] in the second image (also in the range of `[0,255]`) such that:

[image]

There may be a case where we won't get **exactly** an equality, so what you would need to do is find the smallest absolute difference between [image] and [image].  In other words, for a mapping `M`, for each entry of [image], we must find an intensity [image] such that:

[image]

You would do this for all 256 values, and we would produce a mapping.  Once you find this mapping, you simply have to apply this mapping on the first image to get it to look like the intensity distribution of the second image.  A rough (and perhaps inefficient) algorithm would look something like this.  Let `im1` be the first image (of type `uint8`) while `im2` is the second image (of type `uint8`):

```
M = zeros(256,1,'uint8'); %// Store mapping - Cast to uint8 to respect data type
hist1 = imhist(im1); %// Compute histograms
hist2 = imhist(im2);
cdf1 = cumsum(hist1) / numel(im1); %// Compute CDFs
cdf2 = cumsum(hist2) / numel(im2);

%// Compute the mapping
for idx = 1 : 256
    [~,ind] = min(abs(cdf1(idx) - cdf2));
    M(idx) = ind-1;
end

%// Now apply the mapping to get first image to make
%// the image look like the distribution of the second image
out = M(double(im1)+1);
```

`out` should contain your matched image where it transforms the intensity distribution of the first image to match that of  the second image.  Take special care of the `out` statement.  The intensity range of `im1` spans between `[0,255]`, but MATLAB's indexing for arrays starts at **1**.  Therefore, we need to add 1 to every value of `im1` so we can properly index into `M` to produce our output.  However, `im1` is of type `uint8`, and MATLAB saturates values should you try and go beyond 255.  As such, to ensure that we get to 256, we must cast to a data type that is beyond 8-bit precision.  I decided to use `double`, then when we add 1 to every value in `im1`, we will span between 1 to 256 so we can properly index into `M`. Also take not that when I find the location that minimizes the difference, I also must subtract by 1 as the data type spans from `[0,255]`.

Comment: please see this link: [link](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/contrast_transform/node3.html)

Comment: @abbasmahmudi Other than normalizing the `cumsum` result, the code is correct.  The block diagram proves it, but thank you for the link!

Comment: @abbasmahmudi - You're welcome.  I forgot about normalizing by the total number of pixels to properly calculate the CDF.  Thank you for the correction, and good luck!

Comment: Yes. Equalize each place separately. It's what is usually done though not ideal.

Comment: @rayryeng what is `nume1`?

Comment: @mLstudent33: That's `numel`, L ending with an L.  It calculates the number of elements in a matrix: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html