# MATLAB: How to reverse back imhistmatch Operation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 2 grayscale images, `A` and `B`. I'm using `imhistmatch` for these images. Assume that the image we obtain after `imhistmatch` is `C` and `A` is our reference.

I  firstly wonder whether `imhistmatch` function is doing a linear operation or not. How can I do reverse operation which convert `C` image to `B` image back?

Comment: In general, no. Imagine your `B` image contains values `50, 51, 52` and these are all transformed to `63` in `C`. How do you transform `63` back into the original values?

Comment: Ok, then is there any way to transform different contrasts but have structurally same images with a reversable operation?

Comment: `imhistmatch` is not a linear operation so it is not possible to reverse the effects that it does on an image.

Comment: @rayryeng I understand actually that point from your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763974/histogram-matching-of-two-images-without-using-histeq. However what I wonder was to find an operation which is linear.